# perl chomp not stripping terminating LF on a string - cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin

I have a string that I am attempting to get the linefeed character at the end deleted.

```
Sample string with linefeed termination**LF**
```

chomp is not removing the linefeed.

If I use chop, in the example above, the last n in 'termination' is getting deleted.

I am getting this string via HTML::PARSER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html), `chomp` removes the string that is present in `$/`.
It isn't always `\n`

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

```
$string =~ s/\R//g;
```

Description for `\R` is available in [`perlrebackslash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc).

Answer (score 2):

If `chop` removes the `n`, then the string doesn't end in a LF. It ends with the `n`.

This well help you see what a string actually contains:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Dumper($str));
```

Comment: @Flimzy, Reread the question. He tried both `chomp` and `chop`.